Can't get device token from react-native-notifications on ios
I have an app on iOS and can't get the device token from the notifications.

I'm running on device
I don't see any relevant message in the logs
I see the prompt to ask for notifications

Here is the relevant code:
  useEffect(() => {
    Notifications.registerRemoteNotifications();
  
    Notifications.events().registerRemoteNotificationsRegistered(event => {
      console.log('DEVICE TOKEN');
      console.log(event.deviceToken);
      alert('DEVICE TOKEN');
      alert(event.deviceToken);
    });
  });


Did you add Push Notifications as a capability in Xcode?

@Piepants thx a lot, I added the capabilities before but reverted it a few times trying out different libraries. That was it, I was able to get the device token


Did you add Push Notifications as a capability in Xcode? – @Piepants

That was it, I was missing the capabilities.


I haven't researched the issue, but here's a suggestion: It would be more stable to use Expo Notifications or React Native Firebase Messaging. If you don't have any specific requirements, you can consider using these packages.
And use can use empty dependency list for useEffect. Like this:
useEffect(() => {
   Notifications.registerRemoteNotifications();

   Notifications.events().registerRemoteNotificationsRegistered( 
     event => {
     console.log('DEVICE TOKEN');
     console.log(event.deviceToken);
     alert('DEVICE TOKEN');
     alert(event.deviceToken);
   });
},[])


I don't want the complexity of expo or to use an external service like firebase for now. Also thanks for the dependency list, I forgot.
